# Increasing the melting point of metal

Tags: physical-chemistry, metals, chemical-compounds

I need to know how one can increase the melting point of a metals like steel, tungsten or ... about 500 degrees and without destroying its shape?

Comment: Don't think that that's possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_point  It only depends on the pressure , 5oo degrees is too much https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0906/0906.3331.pdf and will not be the same for all solids

Comment: What units ?  Is it $500^\circ K$, $500^\circ C$ or $500^\circ F$ ?

Comment: you can easily achieve it by switching from Celsius to Fahrenheit

Comment: The unit is centigrade.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the steel with tungsten/wolfram. Certain alloys have higher melting points than their component metals ([TaHfC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum_hafnium_carbide) is a case in point: it melts at 3,990 °C but TaC melts at 3,880 °C, Ta at 3017°C, HfC at 3,928 °C, and Hf at 2233°C).

But basically there is no magical way of increasing melting points without changing the material; pressure and magnetic effects are very minor.

Or you could add cooling behind or around the metal to remove heat. This is [how jet engines can run hotter than the melting point of their blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbine_blade#Film_cooling).

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very useful. Would you please introduce some alloys with melting point  higher that 4000 C?

Comment: I asked, without destroying its shape, I mean if it is a  sphere, and we put it in a furnace, the sphere does not change during the process.

Comment: Would you please explain more regarding "you could add cooling behind the metal."?